# after ajax load grid massaction additional form not working

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, order-grid

i am adding the mass action from observer that are work perfectly but after the ajax load grid it is not working. cannot show the additional form.

copying this code from **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid**

```
$groups = $this->helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();

        array_unshift($groups, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('assign_group', array(
             'label'        => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Assign a Customer Group'),
             'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignGroup'),
             'additional'   => array(
                'visibility'    => array(
                     'name'     => 'group',
                     'type'     => 'select',
                     'class'    => 'required-entry',
                     'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
                     'values'   => $groups
                 )
            )
        ));


$orderstatus = Mage::helper('modulename')->getStatus();

            array_unshift($orderstatus, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
                $block->addItem('orderstatus', array(
                    'label' => 'Order Status',
                    'url' => $url,

                    'additional'   => array(
                    'visibility'    => array(
                         'name'     => 'status',
                         'type'     => 'select',
                         'class'    => 'required-entry',
                         'label'    => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Status'),
                         'values'   => $orderstatus
                     )
                )


                ));
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you show us your complete code as this snippet is probably not enough to get a good answer from.

Comment: this method i used in observer to add action in order gird but after ajax call sub option are not working.

Comment: update my question check it

Comment: What do you mean after the ajax call?

Comment: grid ajax call. when grid content update with ajax

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console? Remember that you need to do `delete window['console']` in chrome to get any output

Comment: Also can you explain what is not working? Do you mean sorting etc?

Comment: when i select the mass action the additional(select) is not showing before ajax grid load is working fine

Comment: it is not browser issue

Comment: i have added answer for your problem i have spent some time to work with your code and problem and i come with some solution for you, hope my answer will work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After carefully examine your code so i found where is your problem. it is prototype handler problem. can not create the handler for this action. if i edit the core file it is working other after ajax reload grid it is not working. So i create the simple solution add my javascript function on ajax call and it is working.

so finally you add this function in your code and your problem will be resolved:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("sales_order_grid_massaction-select").observe("change", function(event) {
      $("sales_order_grid_massaction-form-additional").update($("sales_order_grid_massaction-item-set_subgroup-block").innerHTML);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt it is not magento way of doing but at least solve the problem..